# Comparing two sets of polylines intersecting polygons and get a matrix of gained/lost connections

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, intersection, network-analyst, adjacency

I have three feature classes, one is of Polygons and the other two of Polylines, representing a set of areas in a city and a network of transit lines between those areas - one network for current service and another with some changes in it. There's no topological connection between the feature classes.

1. First I'd like to map out the service between all polygons in the city, in pairs - like in an Adjacency Matrix. As in "How many lines are connecting A & B?" Doing so for each set of two polygons. This process will repeat itself for both sets of polylines, in order to build two adjacency matrices, i.e. how many routes connect each pair of polygons.
2. Then I'd like to compare the results of both networks and find how the service between areas of the city has changed - and return a numeric value of lost/gained connections. For example in TABLE 1, there's one new connection between A&C, and zero new connections between C&D (which has changed between lines yet retained one connecting line).
3. If that's too complicated it would be sufficient to get something like in TABLE 2, in which every pair of polygons gets one field, and each line gets a row. In that way I could see which changes occurred and highlight problems at the individual line level.
   [image]

I thought of doing many INTERSECT commands for each polygon and to calculate pairs manually in Excel, but how can I automate the process for example for 80 lines * 30 Polygons or more? I use both ArcMap and QGIS but I'm far from an expert in those...

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately, this doesn't conform to the One question per Question policy (two platforms is two questions). This is also a rather involved task, which doesn't address the questions "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?"  If automation is the goal, then you need to include a best effort at coding at least a piece of the problem.

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I don't code at all, I thought there's a tool that can do this, that I didn't find yet. I'm quite new to GIS and quite basic with my experience, I'm more an Excel guy so I thought there's some kind of tool similar to "pivot", yet a Geospatial one.

Comment: I haven't heard of one, but I've only been involved with GIS for 35 years (nearly all of it building custom tools for exotic tasks).  If that's your goal, you should [Edit] the question to include it, but I suspect you'll be doing some coding. The good news is that Python is an easy language to learn, and it's built to handle list iteration.